# Concatenate a string with a binding

Tags: xaml

I need the complete url source to bind the image but I have only the `imagePath` string which has only the `folderName/theImage.png`, can I concatenate the localhost path like this :

```xml
<Image Source="localhost:port/"+"{Binding imagePath}"></Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to add another property to your data source with the base uri.

However, if you can't change the class, you can use a converter:

XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:StringToUrlConverter x:Key="StringToUrlConverter" BaseUri="https://www.fillmurray.com/"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath, Converter={StaticResource StringToUrlConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```cs
public class StringToUrlConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new Uri(BaseUri + value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string BaseUri
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.